# Installing syui/hugo-theme-arch theme with blogdown

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown, toml, blogdown

I am working on creating a website using markdown package from Rstudio. When I run a function:

```
blogdown::install_theme('syui/hugo-theme-arch',theme_example =TRUE)
```

Return the error:

> Error in find_config(): Cannot find the configuration file config.yaml
>   or config.toml of the website

My code is:

```
devtools::install_github('rstudio/blogdown')
blogdown::install_hugo()
blogdown::install_theme('syui/hugo-theme-arch',theme_example =TRUE)
```

Comment: Have you set your working directory to the directory of your site? When `find_config()` complains like that, it can be because it can't find the config file of *your* site, not the theme. For example, if you are not in the wd of your site and you try to run blogdown functions, it will give you this error.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you need to first use blogdown's `new_site` function. I think it is trying to update a config file that doesn't yet exist, since the `install_theme` function has `update_config` argument which defaults to TRUE .